# What is correct syntax to use AWK in VBScript?

Tags: vbscript

I have a VBScript which Telnets into a Linux device and I would like to see the available memory.  The following command produces an "Invalid procedure call or argument" error.

```
WshShell.SendKeys"df /mnt/cf | awk '/mnt/{print$2}'"
```

This works if I manually telnet into the device and use the same command. Any advice?

Code so far:

```
Dim WshShell

Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.run"cmd" 
'*** open command window *** 
WScript.Sleep 250 WshShell.SendKeys("{Enter}") 
WshShell.SendKeys"telnet 10.13.2.2 -f VBSmemSize.txt" 
WshShell.SendKeys("{Enter}") 
WScript.Sleep 2000 
WshShell.SendKeys"root" 
WshShell.SendKeys("{Enter}") 
WScript.Sleep 1500 
WshShell.SendKeys"password" 
WshShell.SendKeys("{Enter}") 
WScript.Sleep 1500 
WshShell.SendKeys"df /mnt/cf |awk '/mnt/{print$2}'" 
WshShell.SendKeys("{Enter}")
```

Comment: I updated your question to include the code you sent me in your comment

Answer (score 1):

I'm not too familiar with it, but does this work:

```
Dim oShell  

set oShell = wscript.createObject("wscript.shell") 

oShell.Run "df /mnt/cf | awk '/mnt/{print$2}'"

Set oShell = Nothing
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion but still no luck.  I will place the full code that I was using for a clearer picture.

Comment: Sorry I can't help you more...  I've exhausted my expertise in this area.  But if I come across anything helpful, I'll be sure to let you know!

Comment: Thanks anyways. I will try to find alternatives if this ca't be solved.

Answer (score 0):

The error character is '{', this is a special one.
You could use '{}' to surround with those special character.
For example,

```
WshShell.SendKeys"df /mnt/cf |awk '/mnt/{{}print$2{}}'"
```